# How to get first value from first row and last value from last row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, min

I have a table in SQL Server as below

```
+---+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|Id | FromCity    | ToCity      |  RequestId  | 
+---+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 1 | Mysore      | Atlanta     | 12          |
+---+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 2 | Atlanta     | Singapore   | 12          |
+---+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 3 | Singapore   | Pakistan    | 12          |
+---+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 4 | Pakistan    | Myscot      | 12          |
+---+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 5 | Rome        | Singapore   | 13          |
+---+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Here, I am trying to get a value as From and To Cities (Round Trip Data) (**i.e. Mysore - > Myscot for the RequestId =12**). Ho to get this value?

When I pass RequestId=12, I should get the value as **Mysore -> Myscot**

I Tried as below:

```
SELECT  MIN(FromCity) [From],
        MAX(ToCity) [To]
FROM    MyTable
WHERE   RequestId = 12
```

But I'm getting Mysore -> Singapore (based on string MIN and MAX).

Comment: is there any logic ? Mysore - > Myscot to is not ,you have to back Mysore

Comment: Logic is I need to show this in a report as Mysore -> Myscot  as roundtrip

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand the question, but I think you are looking for a recursive cte.

Comment: Add a few more rows of sample data, and also specify the expected result.

Comment: i don't really get what you are trying to do. what from date and to date come from (which fields). city max and min would be alphabetical order, is this what you want?

Comment: What defines the first and last rows? (ie. what sort condition do you want?)

Comment: I have updated the Question.

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to use CTE to achieve that

Comment: @55SK55 your question doesn't seem to have anything to do with first and lasts. You are asking how to follow a path from an origin city to a destination city in a graph of city-to-city paths. You can't do that just by sorting the data. You'll need to use a recursive CTE. In SQL Server 2017 and 2019 you can also use graph tables to traverse the graph

Answer (score 2):

Check This :

```
SELECT  M.FromCity [From],
        M2.ToCity [To]
FROM    #MyTable M
Inner join (select Min(ID) min ,Max(ID) max  from #MyTable M2  WHERE  M2.RequestId = 12 )
A on A.Min =ID
Inner join #MyTable M2 on M2.ID=A.Max
```

> Output :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The only logic I see is using the `Id` from your table and do something like this. Using `CTE` you will find the `MIN` and `MAX` id per request, that means from city - to city.
And after that you join your table to the CTE to find the actual values.

```
declare @tbl as table
    ([Id] int, [FromCity] varchar(9), [ToCity] varchar(9), [Date Created] datetime, [RequestId] int)
;

INSERT INTO @tbl
    ([Id], [FromCity], [ToCity], [Date Created], [RequestId])
VALUES
    (1, 'Mysore', 'Atlanta', '2018-10-05 15:10:00', 12),
    (2, 'Atlanta', 'Singapore', '2018-10-06 15:10:00', 12),
    (3, 'Singapore', 'Pakistan', '2018-10-07 15:10:00', 12),
    (4, 'Pakistan', 'Myscot', '2018-10-07 15:10:00', 12),
    (5, 'UK', 'Atlanta', '2018-10-06 15:10:00', 13),
    (6, 'Atlanta', 'Singapore', '2018-10-06 15:10:00', 13),
    (7, 'Singapore', 'Italy', '2018-10-23 15:10:00', 13);


;with cte as (
    select
        MIN(Id) as [start]
        ,MAX(Id) as [end]
        ,RequestId
    from @tbl
    group by requestID
)

select
    t1.FromCity
    ,t1.[Date Created]
    ,t2.ToCity
    ,t2.[Date Created]
from cte 
inner join @tbl t1
    on t1.Id = cte.[start]
    and t1.RequestId = cte.RequestId
inner join @tbl t2
    on t2.Id = cte.[end]
    and t2.RequestId = cte.RequestId
```

---

Update: based on @Panagiotis Kanavos comment you can simplify the query like this

```
;with cte as (
    select
        MIN(Id) as [start]
        ,MAX(Id) as [end]
    from @tbl
    where RequestId = 12  ---> here you can use a variable containing the requestID
)

select
    t1.FromCity
    --,t1.[Date Created]
    ,t2.ToCity
    --,t2.[Date Created]
from cte 
inner join @tbl t1
    on t1.Id = cte.[start]
inner join @tbl t2
    on t2.Id = cte.[end]
```

Comment: The table defines a graph from `Mysore` to `Myscot`. The question seems to be how to find the starting and ending point of that graph when all you have is the "graph ID", ie `RequestId`

Answer (score 1):

If Id in main table is used to describe travel order then something like this will work:

```
SELECT startLocation.FromCity [From], endLocation.ToCity AS [To]
FROM (
SELECT MIN(Id) AS StartLocationId, MAX(Id) AS EndLocationId
FROM    MyTable
WHERE   RequestId = 12 
) AS a
INNER JOIN MyTable AS startLocation ON a.StartLocationId = startLocation.Id
INNER JOIN MyTable AS endLocation ON a.EndLocationId = endLocation.Id
```

This is a example of solution for situation when ids are just ids and don`t match travel order:

```
declare @tbl as table
    ([Id] int, [FromCity] varchar(9), [ToCity] varchar(9), [Date Created] datetime, [RequestId] int)
;

INSERT INTO @tbl
    ([Id], [FromCity], [ToCity], [Date Created], [RequestId])
VALUES
    (19, 'Mysore', 'Atlanta', '2018-10-05 15:10:00', 12),
    (22, 'Atlanta', 'Singapore', '2018-10-06 15:10:00', 12),
    (1, 'Singapore', 'Pakistan', '2018-10-07 15:10:00', 12),
    (4, 'Pakistan', 'Myscot', '2018-10-07 15:10:00', 12),
    (5, 'UK', 'Atlanta', '2018-10-06 15:10:00', 13),
    (0, 'Atlanta', 'Singapore', '2018-10-06 15:10:00', 13),
    (-1, 'Singapore', 'Italy', '2018-10-23 15:10:00', 13)
;

select * from @tbl

declare @Id int = 12
declare @FromStart nvarchar(255), @ToStart nvarchar(255) 
declare @StartResult nvarchar(255), @ToResult nvarchar(255) 
declare @StartResultFound bit = 0, @ToResultFound bit = 0

-- select random starting point
select @FromStart = [FromCity], @ToStart = [ToCity] from @tbl where [RequestId] = @Id
ORDER BY NEWID()

select @FromStart, @ToStart

while (@StartResultFound = 0)
begin
    if exists (select top 1 1 from @tbl where [RequestId] = @Id and [ToCity] = @FromStart)
    begin
        select top 1 @FromStart = [FromCity] from  @tbl where [RequestId] = @Id and [ToCity] = @FromStart
    end
    else
    begin
        set @StartResultFound = 1
        set @StartResult = @FromStart
    end
end

while (@ToResultFound = 0)
begin
    if exists (select top 1 1 from @tbl where [RequestId] = @Id and [FromCity] = @ToStart)
    begin
        select top 1 @ToStart = [ToCity] from  @tbl where [RequestId] = @Id and [FromCity] = @ToStart
    end
    else
    begin
        set @ToResultFound = 1
        set @ToResult = @ToStart
    end
end

select @StartResult, @ToResult
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  RequestId, 
        f.FromCity [From],
        t.ToCity [To]
FROM    MyTable t
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT TOP (1) FromCity
        FROM MyTable
        WHERE RequestId = t.RequestId
        ORDER BY Id ASC
    ) f
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT TOP (1) ToCity
        FROM MyTable
        WHERE RequestId = t.RequestId
        ORDER BY Id DESC
    ) t
WHERE   RequestId = 12
```

Answer (score 1):

A recursive version, not depending on `Id`s order. The idea is to build the biggest chain of trip connected by To / From cities.

```
WITH cte1 AS (
-- start with all trips as 1 hop chain
  SELECT [FromCity], [ToCity], 1 AS HOP 
  FROM Mytable 
  WHERE REQUESTID = 12
UNION ALL
  -- recursively add one hop if we find a trip ending in start city of the chain
  SELECT T.[FromCity], cte1.[ToCity], cte1.HOP + 1 
  FROM cte1
  JOIN Mytable t 
    ON t.[ToCity] = cte1.[FromCity]
  WHERE t.REQUESTID = 12
)
, cte2 AS (
  -- order by number of hops 
  SELECT [FromCity], [ToCity], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY HOP DESC) AS N
  FROM cte1
)
-- choose the chain with the more hops
SELECT [FromCity], [ToCity] 
FROM cte2 
WHERE N = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe this is whar you need

```
DECLARE 
    @t TABLE (
        ID INT
    ,   FromCity VARCHAR(250)
    ,   ToCity   VARCHAR(250)
    ,   RequestId   INT 
    )

INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
 (1,'Mysore','Atlanta',12)
,(2,'Atlanta','Singapore',12)
,(3,'Singapore','Pakistan',12)
,(4,'Pakistan','Myscot',12)
,(5,'Rome','Singapore',13)


SELECT DISTINCT 
    ISNULL(FromCity, ISNULL(NextCity, PreCity) ) FromCity
,   ISNULL(ToCity, ISNULL(NextCity2, PreCity2) ) FromCity
FROM (
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN FromCity END FromCity
,   CASE WHEN RN = CNT THEN ToCity END  ToCity
,   LEAD(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN FromCity END)  OVER(PARTITION BY RequestId ORDER BY ID) NextCity
,   LEAD(CASE WHEN RN = CNT THEN ToCity END)  OVER(PARTITION BY RequestId ORDER BY ID) NextCity2
,   LAG(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN FromCity END)  OVER(PARTITION BY RequestId ORDER BY ID) PreCity
,   LAG(CASE WHEN RN = CNT THEN ToCity END)  OVER(PARTITION BY RequestId ORDER BY ID) PreCity2
FROM (
SELECT 
*,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY RequestId ORDER BY ID) RN
,   COUNT(ToCity) OVER(PARTITION BY RequestId) CNT
FROM @t
) D
WHERE 
    RN = 1 OR RN = CNT 
) C
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

SELECT  MIN(Id) [From],
        MAX(Id) [To]
FROM    MyTable
WHERE   RequestId = 12